# set default database

Tags: php, adodb

How can I set a default database on an adodb connection?

```
$ldap = NewADOConnection( 'ldap' ); 
$ldap->Connect( $host, $user_name='', $password='', $ldapbase );
???
```

Example:

```
$db->execute("UPDATE  `DEFAULT`.`table` SET  `stg` =  '$stg';
```

Comment: It is just a name of it. I'm expecting something like: $db->SetDefaultDatabase("DEFAULT");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DefaultDatabase` property to set or return a string value that is the default database. Like

```
conn.DefaultDatabase="northwind"
```